# All elements after first occurrence of closest element or first nearest by element

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

How would you write a function in JS for the following:
Get the subarray of all elements:

- after and including the first occurrence of the searched element
- or after and including the first number greater than the searched element.

These tests should pass:

```
expect(elementsStartingFrom([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11], 1)).toEqual([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]);
expect(elementsStartingFrom([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11], 2)).toEqual([3, 5, 7, 9, 11]);
expect(elementsStartingFrom([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11], 3)).toEqual([3, 5, 7, 9, 11]);
expect(elementsStartingFrom([1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 5], 2)).toEqual([3, 5, 1, 4, 5]);
```

Comment: you should just just iterate over array and when you find first value that is equal or greater than current element then use the current index to return slice of the array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Could you show what you've tried yourself first? At the moment it feels like you're asking us to solve your code.

Answer (score 0):

First, use `indexOf` to see if the item is in the list. If not, `filter` out anything less than, `sort` that to get next biggest, then use `indexOf` to find the index of that. Finally, use `slice` to get the part of the array:

```
const elementsStartingFrom = (haystack, needle) => {
    let idx = haystack.indexOf(needle);
    if (-1 == idx) {
        const tmp = haystack.filter(i => i > needle).sort((a, b) => a - b).at(0);
        idx = haystack.indexOf(tmp);
    }
    if (idx == -1) return null;
    else return haystack.slice(idx);
};
```

You could remove the first call to `indexOf` and get the same result by changing the `<` to `<=`:

```
const elementsStartingFrom = (haystack, needle) => {
    const tmp = haystack.filter(i => i >= needle).sort((a, b) => a - b).at(0);
    const idx = haystack.indexOf(tmp);
    return (idx == -1) ? null : haystack.slice(idx);
};
```